# cannot load sketchup file properly in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, sketchup

I am new in `Unity3d` and i have been trying to import a `Sketchup` 3d model in unity by following this tutorial [Imoprting Models in Unity3d From SketchUp](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/importing-models-unity-3d-from-google-sketchup-muhammad-faizan-atiq). I have followed all the steps correctly but when i use the model in `Unity`. its missing all its `Materials` and `Texture`. It looks like this:

[image]

Can someone help me to find what i am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create new material, add texture to created material and attach material in MeshRenderer component.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please.